# Run application after Outlook sends email

Tags: email, outlook

We have an automated process which pulls call data from Avaya CMS and compiles the data into an email based report.  The report is sent out via Outlook 2010. At times the automate process fails and an email is generated with the subject line "ASR - ERROR OCCURRED".  Currently using rules this error message is forwarded to a few individuals for corrective action.  Question is could an action be built in Outlook that would recognize the subject and perform the steps of relaunching the automated application?

There's two cache files that manually need deleted and one *.exe to run.  Currently I have a *.bat file on the desktop of the computer to delete the files and then we have to manually choose the correct *.exe file depending upon the time the report ran.

Thank you

Comment: Why can the automated process not take care of itself?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  The original developer has left the company.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Script to run as part of a rule from Outlook, however this will only work with Outlook open:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108

A similar question was asked here:
[Outlook rule to run VBA script that runs external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805614/outlook-rule-to-run-vba-script-that-runs-external-program)

To just run the application there is a Start Application action (in 2013, not sure about 2010)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Did some work on this today and came up with this which seems to do the trick.

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal objItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

```
Dim mi As MailItem

Dim batPath As String

Dim TMin As Integer

batPath = "C:\Users\sxxxxxx\Desktop\"


If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then

    Set mi = objItem


    If mi.Subject = "ASR - ERROR OCCURRED" Then


        Call Shell(batPath & "cms cache del.bat") 'clears all cache files and stops process

        TMin = Right(Format$(Now(), "Short Time"), 2)

        If TMin < 10 Or TMin > 30 Then    'determine based on when error occurred which report to re-run


            Call Shell(batPath & "XXXX.bat")


        Else

            Call Shell(batPath & "XXXX.bat")


        End If

    End If

End If
```

End Sub